# Merge two distinct table having completely different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to merge two variables (tables) in my script. Variable one has three columns and 54 rows. Variable two has four columns and 1 row. This 1 row will be propagated for all the 54 rows from the first variable. I want to combine these columns side by side into one table variable.

I'm pretty much new to SQL Server and stackoverflow community. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!
[image]
Edit: -
Thanks for responding on my question. Let me try my best to put the sample tables here. To simplify please assume column names are A, B, ..G

Table 1
|  A  | B |  C   |
+-----+---+------+
|  86 | 0 | 4711 |
|  86 | 0 | 4712 |
| 86  | 0 | 4713 |
|  86 | 0 | 4714 |
+-----+---+------+

Table2
+------+------+------+---------+
|  D   |  E   |  F   |    G    |
+------+------+------+---------+
| True | Null | Null | 00:00.0 |
+------+------+------+---------+

Expected Result
 A  | B |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |    G    |
+----+---+------+------+------+------+---------+
| 86 | 0 | 4711 | TRUE | Null | Null | 00:00.0 |
| 86 | 0 | 4712 | TRUE | Null | Null | 00:00.0 |
| 86 | 0 | 4713 | TRUE | Null | Null | 00:00.0 |
| 86 | 0 | 4714 | TRUE | Null | Null | 00:00.0 |
+----+---+------+------+------+------+---------+

Comment: Show us some sample table data for each table, and also the combined result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a cross join:

```
select *
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

So depending on what you want to achieve, let mi visualize.

Let's say you have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Bar
(
  BarId INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Foo
(
   FooId INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Bar(BarId) VALUES
(1),
(2);

INSERT INTO Foo(FooId) VALUES
(10),
(20),
(30);
```

1. Cross join is a Cartesian product so the data will be a multiplication of two sets to form the set of all ordered pairs

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Output

```
| FooId | BarId |
|-------|-------|
|    10 |     1 |
|    20 |     1 |
|    30 |     1 |
|    10 |     2 |
|    20 |     2 |
|    30 |     2 |
```

2. Full outer join will show you all values from right and left table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name ON (1 = 0) --nothing we can match those tables on
```

Output

```
|  FooId |  BarId |
|--------|--------|
|     10 | (null) |
|     20 | (null) |
|     30 | (null) |
| (null) |      1 |
| (null) |      2 |
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/74d24/1

Answer (score 0):

As I can see all of this soultions provided so far will give you a correct answer.
And also will this older approach:

```
select * 
from table1, table2
```

Here is a small demo where you can see example of this solutions in action:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daac030e2971db13e57e90da7378db20

Comment: While this is true, I doubt that the OP uses a DBMS that makes it necessary to use this obsolete join syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try below simple way:

```
select * from tableA left join tableB as tableC on 1 = 1;
```

Above query brings all the columns from both the table.

Comment: A left join is an outer join that keeps rows from the first table even when there is no match in the second one. `1 = 1` however is always true, so there is no outer join happening here. It's a mere inner join. And as `1 = 1` has no reference to the rows in question, this is no condition at all. So, not even an inner join actually, but a **cross join**. I am downvoting this answer hence. I suggest you look into joins to learn the differences. After all, these differences are a reason for their invention in 1992.